# What does now refer to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-in-context

I got a message from my bank after doing an online transaction of €110

> You have **now** paid €110 to xxx.

Is this sentence correct?
What does **now** mean here?
Does it mean recently? I am confused because I have already paid the money not just **now**.

I know one of the definitions of now is immediate past ,very recently but I asked the same question to someone else and he said this is not what it means here

It means now; the status of the invoice now is 'paid'. The message was generated at the time 'now' that you paid it and the message remains on the record. You can search for that message ten years from now, and it will still read 'you have now paid...'

I don't even know what did he wanna say as English ain't my native language

Comment: If English *isn't* your native language, you will *want to* take care about using words like "ain't" and "wanna" in text.

Comment: @JamesK - think for a moment - was the OP being jocular?

Answer (score 2):

There is not much difference between "You have paid £110" and "You have now paid £110".

The word now is an adverb it means at the present point in time, and with the perfect tense (have now paid) suggests an action that has just finished.

It doesn't mean that you are currently in the process of paying. It doesn't mean that you now have to pay another 110

The explanation you got is correct: The current state of the invoice is paid.

Comment: Now means immediate past or very recently here?

Comment: I don't see much difference between "the immediate past" and "very recently". To me, they mean the same thing. I'll stick with my explanation: "Have now paid" means the act of paying has just finished (at the time of writing the message).

Comment: Yes there's no difference between very recently and immediate past. Sorry I had say 'immediate past; very recently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "now" means "at this moment" or "very recently". But when you are describing a status, like here, a status of "paid", it doesn't necessarily mean that you acquired that status at just this moment. It can mean that at the present time you are in that status.

Like if I said, "Sally is now married", that doesn't mean that she just got married within the last few minutes. It means that her present status is married. She could have married many years ago.

Someone is unlikely to use the word "now" for a status unless they want to contrast it with a status that the person or object had or will have at some other time. Like I might say, "When I knew her 20 years ago, Sally was single. But now she is married." I would be unlikely to say, "I am now a US citizen", as I have been a US citizen since I was born.

In this case, they are probably contrasting the time before you paid the money to your condition now, where you have paid. When you initiated the transaction you had not yet paid. At some point you paid.

If you access a transaction log 20 years from now and this is still on file, it might well still say, "You have now paid", because your status is still "paid".